# Our Editing Help doesn't mention paragraph breaks

Tags: feature-request

I just took a look at our [Editing Help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and noticed it makes no mention of the fact you need two line breaks for a paragraph break.

^ Like this. This seems to be the thing that *most commonly* trips up new users! Markdown ignores single lines, yet some new users don't know what to do about that. Some do nothing and just have their giant unbroken paragraph with ignored single line breaks, whilst others fill their post with `<br>`'s.

Please change the editing help to mention paragraph breaks at the beginning!

---

Apparently, this has been suggested on Meta.SO already: [Add “paragraphs” to Markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135252/152515)

If you've upvoted or are upvoting this feature request, please drop by that link and upvote it there too!

Comment: Nice, this would have helped when I started out.

Comment: Yeah, right above "Line Breaks" there should be a "Paragraphs: leave a blank line between to make a paragraph break" item. First thing. Very important.

Comment: That said, this should go on Meta.SO for best visibility.

Comment: Yes I was equally baffled by this for a long time.